# NSDateFormatter returns nil for the 2 AM hour

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdateformatter, dst

I'm trying to convert a string to an NSDate using the following code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date= [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2013-03-10T02:00:00"];
```

It works fine for all hours except 02:00:00, shown above, which returns nil.

Any ideas?

Comment: not sure how to fix it, but the problem could be due to daylight saving

Comment: Yep, that's what it is.  Change the date to the 9th or 11th and the problem goes away...

Comment: In the USA, there is no such thing as 2am on March 10, 2013. The time went from 1:59:59 to 3:00:00 due to day light savings time. The same issue will appear in other locales as well but at other dates/times.

Comment: Side Note - there is no need to set the date formatter's time zone to the local timezone. That is set by default.

Comment: @maddy great comment! you should frame an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the **Daylight Savings Time**  that took place in the US on 10th March 2013

The System time directly jumps from 1:59  AM to 3:00 AM..
You lose an hour that you had gained on November when the DST came into effect